# I want my PHP to create ONE table, but it creates SEVERAL

Tags: php, html, html-table

I need to create a table via php with data from my mysql server. I've managed to establish a connection, and I can create a table, but my problem is that it creates a table for each of the rows, whereas I want one unified. This is my code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT navn, institution, klip FROM parkeringsdata';
mysqli_select_db($conn , 'parkeringsdb');
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn , $sql );
echo "<br><br><br>";
if(! $retval ) {
die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

     echo "<table class='content info'>
        <tr>
          <td>Navn</td>
          <td>Institution</td>
          <td>Klip</td>
          <td>Rediger</td>
          <td>Slet</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>".$row["navn"]."</td>
         <td>".$row["institution"]."</td>
         <td>".$row["klip"]."</td>
         <td><button type='button'>Rediger</button></td>
         <td><button type='button'>Slet</button></td>
       </tr></table><br>";
}

echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the quick responses, it's solved now and I see where I made it a rookie mistake. It's for a school assignment and we'd been wracking our brains here :)

Comment: You've the <table> tag within the while loop, that is why you get multiple tables and not rows. Try moving the <table> tag outside the loop and the <tr>'s inside the while loop to get multiple rows in one table.

Comment: In other words: if you don't want to repeat some parts of the code, don't put that code inside the loop that repeats them.

Comment: @Mads Christoffersen, Can you accept an answer which worked the best for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to extract the "", "" and your table-header definition out of the for loop, so it will only be executed once.

And: Creating tables this way is easy to do, but leads to error-prone & difficult to maintain code.

It's okay to learn it step by step.

But most likely you'll want to switch to a templating engine (on client or server side, your&your applications choice) sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I know it would be easier to manage with a templating engine, but this is for a school assignment, and it's required for us to code it.

Comment: Ah, well. Yeah. When school requests you to shoot yourself into your foot to get the grade, you've got no other options. And as stated: Its okay to do it this way as the steps required to learn what you (or the template engine) is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table = "<table class='content info'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

     $table .= "
        <tr>
          <td>Navn</td>
          <td>Institution</td>
          <td>Klip</td>
          <td>Rediger</td>
          <td>Slet</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>".$row["navn"]."</td>
         <td>".$row["institution"]."</td>
         <td>".$row["klip"]."</td>
         <td><button type='button'>Rediger</button></td>
         <td><button type='button'>Slet</button></td>
       </tr>";
}
$table .= "</table><br>";
```

You have table start and end tags inside foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Echo table outside the while loop

```
    $sql = 'SELECT navn, institution, klip FROM parkeringsdata';
mysqli_select_db($conn , 'parkeringsdb');
$retval = mysqli_query( $conn , $sql );
echo "<br><br><br>";
if(! $retval ) {
die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
  echo "<table class='content info'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    echo "<tr>
          <td>Navn</td>
          <td>Institution</td>
          <td>Klip</td>
          <td>Rediger</td>
          <td>Slet</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>".$row["navn"]."</td>
         <td>".$row["institution"]."</td>
         <td>".$row["klip"]."</td>
         <td><button type='button'>Rediger</button></td>
         <td><button type='button'>Slet</button></td>
       </tr>";
}
echo "</table><br>";
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";

mysqli_close($conn);
```